# How to create and use my Generic Type with C#?

Tags: c#, list, generics, search

I am trying to learn generic types and I've written this code:

```
public class MyProp<TDictonary, TValor>
    {
        private List<TDictonary> MyDictionary = new List<TDictonary>();
        private List<TValor> TValue = new List<TValue>();

        public MyProp<TDictonary, TValue> Search(TDictonary dictionary)
        {
            MyProp<TDictonary, TValor> dic = new MyProp<TDictonary, TValor>();
            var test = MyDictionary.FirstOrDefault(item => item == dictionary);
            return dic;
        }
```

So I tried to create something like a C# Dictionary. What I tried to do was to associate TDictionary and TValue to Lists, add them to my generic type and return MyProp with its content. I also plan to add other methods like Add, Remove, etc, but if I'm not able to perform a simple search within a list I certainly won't be able to go any further.

Does anyone know if I'm going down the right path? If not, could you point to the right path?

Thank you.

Comment: @agent-j It won't compile. It gives me this error: Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TDictonary' and 'TDictonary'.

Comment: did you notice your inconsistent spelling? One of the things making this code hard to parse (human parsing I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to create something like a C# Dictionary

You do know about [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) though, right?

Anyway, I’m not sure what your generics (or even the type) are actually meant to represent (give them clearer names!), so I cannot exactly tell you what you have to change to actually search on your dictionary.

However there are a few hints:

- In the method, you create an instance `dic`, do nothing on it and then simply return that – regardless of what you do previously.
- You only work on the `MyDictionary` but completely ignore the `TValue` field.
- Private fields are usually named in `camelCase`, i.e. starting a lower case character.
- Naming a private field `TValue` is *very* confusing, due to the starting `T`. That is usually reserved for generic types only.

> It gives me this error: Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TDictonary' and 'TDictonary'

That’s because the type is a generic type without any restrictions. So it can either be a reference type or a value type, as such the compiler cannot decide about which comparison to do for the `==` operator. A simple, but maybe restricting, fix would be to specify a base type that is either a value type, or a reference type:

```
public class MyProp<TDictonary, TValor>
    where TDictionary : class
```

Comment: Giving you a better answer. Right what I want to create is a generic type that works like C#'s dictionary, just so that I can learn how to work with these types. I read a about them and they seem very useful. In the future I'll need to implement something like a dictionary that will need to take in account lots of informations (string type and the other types will be Classes, let's just call them Person, Animal, Mineral, Vegetal). I know that in the example I gave you could just create one or 2 classes and add them to it, but the real ones will have nothing in common.

Comment: Was I able to explain myself? I really think I didn't, so if you have any questions, please feel fgree to ask me.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, so you want to basically implement your own version of the Dictionary type? I personally don’t think you should do that given that you most probably cannot match the performance of the built-in type. Regardless of that I don’t think “using generics” is a necessary solution to your problem. You usually use generics, if you can create two (or more types) without using generics that have the exact functionality with the type exchanged. That being said, there is nothing preventing your from creating `Dictionary<string, Mineral>` or something.

Comment: @poke It's more insidious than that. One cannot come up with a generic type constraint that will allow `T==T` because of the non-virtual nature of operators (including `==`).

Comment: @pst Restricting it to a reference type (`class`) is enough to make it compile and should use identity comparison for `==`. Of course that won’t make two different (but content-identical) strings equal, but well…

Comment: Oops, you're correct. For some reason I was sure that was still not valid... (I didn't think it would compile at all, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a generic type constraint so you can call `.Equals`

```
public class MyProp<TKey, TValue>
   where TValue : IEquatable<TKey>


MyProp<TDictonary, TValor> prop = new MyProp<TDictonary, TValor>();
var val = MyDictionary.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals(dictionary));
prop.Key = val;
prop.Value = val;
return dic;
```

Comment: Yes. It's a typo. My mistake. English isn't my first language, so I tried to translate my code after I couldn't do anything with it.

Comment: +1 The key distinction is the use of `Equals` and not `==`. Operators can never be invoked in a polymorphic fashion.